# my ceiling fan and light do not work

Tags: electrical

Recently I turned the light switch and my ceiling fan/ light flickered a few times and then turned on.  The next time I turned it on there was nothing so I tried the ceiling fan itself and it came on but no light.  I shut it off and tried it again and no fan no light.  Is this dangerous?  Could there be a fire?  I think I might just need a new light/ceiling fan.  Please help.

Comment: Some one needs to check for loose connections in the ceiling box and at the wall switch

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. When lamps flicker, that means there may be sparking somewhere, which if it continues can generate heat and be quite dangerous. So, please be careful.

Answer (score 1):

When you have a fan/light combo and the lights are flickering or not turning on it generally means you have a problem within the fixture itself. The only thing you can really do is to check the box below the fan and see if any connections there are damaged or loose. Then do the same for the junction box above the fan. If you cannot find anything wrong with the wiring, then it is probably the fixture itself that is going bad. Because repair is usually much more expensive than replacement, I would recommend replacing the entire fixture.

Hope this helps.